# Django coloring output in runserver.py

Tags: django, colors

I want to highlight the output in the console "manage.py runserver"
In Linux, all OK, but in Windows does not work.

The [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/)
says: **SET export DJANGO_COLORS = "light"**

Does not work.
There is a [ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13476) 
Nodule is installed: pip install pyreadline
Not work.

Comment: Please mark the answer as Answered since it seems that it solved your problem.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Did you apply the [patch](http://code.djangoproject.com/attachment/ticket/13476/13476-better.patch) from the ticket? Otherwise it's not going to work.

Comment: After 2 years, you would think it would have been released!